# O bindValue() do PDOStatement não funciona com o nome da tabela?

Tags: php, pdo

Pois bem, tenho seguinte código:

```
public function Ler($tabela="funcionarios"){
        $this->sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM :tabela");
        $this->sql->bindValue(':tabela',$tabela);
        $this->sql->execute();
        return $this->sql->fetchAll();
    }
```

Aí ele retorna um array vazio.

Mas Já este código:

```
public function Ler(){
        $this->sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM funcionarios");
        $this->sql->execute();
        return $this->sql->fetchAll();
    }
```

retorna o array com os registros, por que com o bindValue não funciona?

Desde Já, Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Não, a substituição de valores com `bindValue` não funciona com todas as partes do comando, como o comando em si (select, update, etc), nem com nomes de campos ou da tabela, funciona com os valores no `values`, `where`, etc.

Isso precisa ser feito antes, assim por exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabela";
$this->sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
```